# two monitors one smartTV setup

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I have a desktop with an intel HD 4600 graphics card and my setup looks as follows:
two monitors (one VGA and one DVI) and a smartTV with HDMI. 
I want to do the following: 
duplicate my main screen to the smartTV and extend the desktop on my second monitor.

This seems impossible to do, either the screen gets duplicated on all 3 screens or one screen turns itself off. When the correct settings are trying to be applied in windows "Screen Resolution" i get the error message it cannot be applied.

What kind of setup do I need to get this all working like I want it to? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your gpu supports more than 2 displays at a time?? The support for more than 2 gpu at a time was added recently. Like for Nvidia cards, it was added for Kepler and above. You may need to check that for your amd card. 
Also, if you are trying to apply though catalyst center,it could be a bug. Try setting from mscpl (screen resolution pane) instead.

Comment: I checked this website http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033714.htm and it does show that the HD4600 supports 3 monitors. Am i doing something wrong?